# Swift ios didSelectItemAt not called until second click

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My `didSelectItemAt` function is not being executed until I click on a second cell, but it is executing with the data obtained from the first cell clicked. Otherwise everything is working as expected. Help?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let id = boardArray[indexPath.row]
    let boardId = id.title
    let storyBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let boardViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BoardViewController") as! BoardViewController
    boardViewController.name = boardId
    self.present(boardViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

So after I click a second cell, it will display the 'BoardViewController' with the first cell's boardId & such.

Thanks, Jewell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `didDeselectItemAt` instead of

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { }
```

use

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { }
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! I've been trying everything I can think of since 10am this morning and it was a matter of 2 letters, now it works perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: Good Day =D ........

Comment: Wow! I'm so ashamed that this is my error too I feel the need to comment :'D